# TextArea drop-down menu - Doesn't push down the page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a textarea that provides real-time suggestions as user types the text.
These suggestions are displayed in the dropdown menu.
The issue I am having is that the dropdown menu covers part of the DIV that sits right below the textarea.

I need to push down the page content when the dropdown opens, so entire page content is always visible.

HTML code:

```
<textarea id="tags" class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3'></textarea>

<div id="quickHelpWrapper">
        <br><small><b>Quick Help</b></small>
        <div id="quickHelp">
            Additional Info 1<br>
            Additional Info 2<br>
            Additional Info 3<br>
            Additional Info 4<br>
            Additional Info 5<br>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Essentially, I need the DIV called quickHelpWrapper, pushed down when textarea dropdown opens.

Example on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jarosciak/kjy149p5/

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Can you show the style of these elements?

Comment: Example on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jarosciak/kjy149p5/

Comment: It works just fine. Try to type more than one character. For example the word 'receptor' and wait for a sec, the dropdown will open.

Comment: The jQuery UI autocomplete feature that you are using here positions this element relatively - so you would have to overwrite that. (The `position` option can’t fix this AFAIK, because that only allows to specify where the element will be positioned in relation to another, but it doesn’t allow to specify “no positioning at all please.”) If you overwrite the inline styles coming from the plugin (research, if you don’t know how) for `.ui-autocomplete` with `position: static`, […]

Comment: […] then it will currently show below your “Quick Help” section though, so you might need to make use of the `appendTo` option to get it located directly after your input field in the DOM

Comment: I've tried to change the position on .ui-menu .ui-autocomplete{position: static;}  but that doesn't even shows it below the "Quick Help" div. Having issues with this...

Comment: See my answer please, complete steps and modified version of your fiddle example in there :-)

Comment: Once again, thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery UI autocomplete feature that you are using here positions this element relatively - so you would have to overwrite that. (The `position` option can’t fix this AFAIK, because that only allows to specify where the element will be positioned in relation to another, but it doesn’t allow to specify “no positioning at all please.”)

You can solve this via these three steps:

Put a container element around the textarea (because we can’t append elements directly to the textarea):

```
<div id="foo">
  <textarea id="tags" class='autoExpand' rows='3' data-min-rows='3'></textarea>
</div>
```

Add the `appendTo` option to your autocomplete initialization:

```
.autocomplete({
  delay: 50,
  minLength: 1,
  multiline: true,
  autoFocus: true,
  appendTo: '#foo',
  source: function(request, response) {
    …
```

And finally, add this to your stylesheet to overwrite the `position: relative` inline style this plugin sets,

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position: static !important;
}
```

Your example, modified accordingly: https://jsfiddle.net/kjy149p5/17/

Comment: This is awesome, works like a charm. I wouldn't be able to figure this out without your help. Much appreciated, you've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

added css:

```
.ui-menu.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-autocomplete
{
  position:relative;
  max-width:524px;
}
```

linky:

https://jsfiddle.net/kjy149p5/20/